# replace every occurrence that is unquoted

Tags: ruby, regex, vim

I'm trying to write a regex in Vim to replace every occurrence of `true` with `'t'` and `false` with `'f'` in an SQL file. To complicate this, I shouldn't replace `true` or `false` when they occur anywhere inside quotes.

I'm using the following regex which almost works:

```
%s/\v^(([^'"]*)|(.*('.*'|".*").*)*)\zs((t)rue|(f)alse)/'\6\7'/
#       no qts or even number of qts   \6     \7
```

But with one small problem: It only replaces one set of `true`s and `false`s per run. E.g. (matches highlighted in bold):

`INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL, 'string', true, '', NULL, true, false, 1);
 INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL, 'string', true,     NULL, true, false, 1);
 INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL,           true, '', NULL, true, false, 1);
 INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL,           true,     NULL, true, false, 1);`

I've tried all sorts of stuff, and I've searched the internet but can't find anything, so I'm stuck. Are there any regex wizards here who know how I can fix this?

A Vim or Ruby solution would be ideal, but a general solution would be helpful as well.

FYI: This is for a rake task that pulls the remote PG database into a local SQLite3 database.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vim `substitute` along with negative look-behinds and negative look-aheads, along with taking some inspiration from your current attempt:

```
%s/\([\S"']\)\@<!\(\(t\)rue\|\(\(f\)alse\)\)\([\S"']\)\@!/'\3\5'/g
```

The following

```
INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL, 'string true', true, '', NULL, true, false, 1);
INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL, "string false", true,     NULL, true, false, 1);
INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL,           true, '', NULL, true, false, 1);
INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL,           true,     NULL, true, false, 1);
```

Turns into:

```
INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL, 'string true', 't', '', NULL, 't', 'f', 1);
INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL, "string false", 't',     NULL, 't', 'f', 1);
INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL,           't', '', NULL, 't', 'f', 1);
INSERT INTO pages VALUES (42, NULL,           't',     NULL, 't', 'f', 1);
```

Comment: No, it's not `sed`, it's `:help :substitute`.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I was already using `%s` (see update). Did you run these commands with the examples I gave? I fail to see how they solve my problem...

Comment: @Josh - you're right, it wasn't working properly on the example you provided. I've updated the commands so it should work in the case of using `%s`.

Comment: Sorry, but this still doesn't work for the case when you have a string that contains `true`. `"It is true."` → `"It is 't'.` ✗